# MySQL Internal Error Ignored

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: InternalError() in <generator object sql_iter at 0x10efe84b0> ignored
```

When I try to iterate through:

```
select *
from cftut.instances as instances
join cftut.templates as templates on
    templates.subtemplate_id = instances.subtemplate_id
join cftut.users as users on
    users.user_id = instances.user_id
where start >= "2013-08-08 00:00:00" and start < "2013-08-15 00:00:00"
order by instances.user_id, instances.start, instances.subinstance_id
```

The generator error referred to by the objects is defined here:

```
def sql_iter(*statements):
    connection = get_global_connection()
    for statement in statements:
        try:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(statement)
            for row in cursor:
                yield row
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

Finally, this is called by the following code

```
for i, instance in enumerate(sql_iter(
    sql_listed_above
)):
    if i%500==0:
        print '-----', i
    yield changes
```

What could be causing this and why is it saying that it is ignored when it actually stops the program running?

Comment: I can not explain the 'ignored' part, but I'm like 80% sure that this is because not all rows are read. Use connection.cursor(buffered=True).